# Можно ли говорить "уроки на дому у ученика"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить *"уроки на дому у ученика"*?

Comment: Конечно можно. Почему Вы сомневаетесь?

Comment: А что это значит?

Answer (score 2):

> Правильно ли говорить "уроки на дому у ученика"?

Говорили, насколько я помню, просто "*уроки на дому*", без "*у ученика*".  Если это что-то вроде рекламного объявления, то я бы написал "**Уроки у Вас на дому**" или "**Учитель даёт уроки у Вас дома**".  Можно что-нибудь даже ввернуть насчёт комфорта или удобства.

Answer (score 2):

К формальному выражению "(даём уроки) на дому" обычно требуется уточнение, иначе с той же вероятностью можно подумать, что это в доме учителя (у себя на дому для учёбы всех приму - с позиций работника или клиента это либо работа на дому, либо оказание услуги на дому). Как уже замечено, это вполне понятное выражение лучше перефразировать, хотя бы из-за трёх "**у**" подряд. Если сохранять форму, то "у кого" лучше поместить перед этим выражением, уклонившись и от "**у у**ченика" (у вас на дому).

Answer (score 1):

1) Если нет дополнительных указаний, то подразумевается, что уроки проводятся **в доме ученика**: Уроки вокала на дому.

2) В доме **учителя**: Даю уроки английского языка у себя на дому.

3) **Два варианта:** Даю уроки русского языка (с выездом или на дому). Даю уроки английского языка, возможен выезд на дом.

4) В доме **ученика:** Даю уроки с выездом на дом. Даю уроки на дому у клиента или у Вас на дому.